# Describe the image of $\exp{A}$, where $A = \{x+iy \lvert 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le \pi \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on the following exercise:

> Describe the image of $\exp(A)$, where $A = \{x+iy \mid 0 \le x \le 1, \ 0 \le y \le \pi \} \subset \mathbb{C}$.

I do not know quite get what to do in this exercise.

It is obvious that $A$ is a rectangle in the complex plane. From real analysis we know that $e^0 = 1$ and $e^1 = e$, so we found the images of the two vertices $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$. But what more can we say here? Does $e^A$ give a certain geometric figure? Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$\mathrm e^{x+iy}=\mathrm e^x\,\mathrm e^{iy}$.

Now in the Argand-Cauchy plane, the image of $\mathrm e^{iy}$ is a point on the unit circle, and multiplication by a real positive number such as $\mathrm e^{x}$ is an homothety with centre $O$.

Comment: In other words it's a half ring, with inner radius $e^0=1$, outer radius $e^1=e$, all in the upper part of the plane (angle from $0$ to $\pi$)

Comment: @Andrei: Yes, exactly.